# Do people really use "which's" in Of Which and Whose Clauses?

Tags: grammar

I had only known "whose clauses".

> I love the car whose lines are beautiful.

When I came to this kind of sentence, I always be awkward since the clause subject is inanimate.

I just know the second way "[of which](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/clauses-8.html)". This expression is good.
Unexpectedly, there is the 3rd way - "which's" - given by the same website.

> The car which's lines are sleek is beautiful.

I had thought "which's" is a wrong way, never thought there is such a way.
And I rarely see much of this usage. Did you see it in somewhere?

Comment: What is the problem with an inanimate reference? Who said "whose" should only be used with living things.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why you can't use [*whose*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/whose-used-for-inanimate-objects) with inanimate objects in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I would not recommend ever saying "which's". It is not a valid English usage.

English always provides a variety of ways of saying things. If in doubt about one way, try to find a better way which avoids the whole problem. You are right that referring to a car as 'who' is not really recommended (at least in formal written contexts).

So if you come across something that seems a bit unwieldy or awkward, even if technically grammatical, try to put it another way.

Rather than say something very cumbersome like:

> The car of which the lines are sleek is beautiful

Say:

> The car with the sleek lines is beautiful.

And thereby avoid the whole problem.

See this article and especially examples in the first comment on this page [for more examples of how to avoid clunky sentences](https://thewritepractice.com/whose-vs-which-inanimate-objects/) using 'of which'.